# ext3 file system performance tuning: what metrics to monitor

Tags: performance, monitoring, ext3, tuning

I have a high-IO application that is working, and scaling well to date.  Over the past few months we've been trying to look down the road and predict where our next bottlenecks will occur.  One of them is surely the file system.

We are currently monitoring

- Space available
- Read operations per second
- Write operations per second

This seems a bit too sparse to me.  What else should I be watching?  I am not even sure what the 'yellow line' would be for the operations/second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some suggestions

- Look at the read queue size, if your application is highly random, then tweak the readahead in `/sys/block/<dev>/queue/read_ahead_kb` to ensure you're reading data you *need*, not data the OS thinks you need.
- Switch to the deadline scheduler if you haven't already
- use the `noatime` mount option unless you're hosting a mail spool
- mount with `data=writeback` if you've got good backups
- keep an eye on your directory sizes, sure hashed directory inodes help, but if you can hash the data yourself then you'll get more consistent results

Comment: Our directory structure is pretty well hashed as is, but will look again.  What would you suggest as "too big" or "too many files" for a directory?

Comment: Take a look at how squid hashes their proxy store. They've got some good documentation on choosing a hashing depth and the tradeoffs

Comment: I agree with noatime but I can't really recommend setting the FS to writeback mode.